# What will formatting linux partitions do?

Tags: partitioning, windows-10

If I format the Linux partitions, what will happen? Will I have to restore the master boot record with a Windows installation CD?
One more thing, how do I identify Linux partitions?
I am dual booting with Windows 10

Comment: As always , it depends =) As far as I know, windows 10 does not recognize linux partitions.

Answer (score 0):

If you format a partition, the MBR is not destroyed. However, the partition table entry for the partition you format might get changed.

Windows sometimes has a problem with changing partitions and sometimes doesn't. Your Windows might fail to boot after you formatted or partitioned but you can "fix" this with the Windows DVD. It basically takes forever to show you the option, then takes a second to do actual stuff, then it is finished.

Comment: The thing is, I'm trying to format the Linux partitions. What will happen then?

Comment: First of all, you won't be able to format a partition currently in use which means that if it's a system partition, you have to do it from outside the system (other operating system on the computer, live system (usb stick, dvd, ...), hard drive plugged into another computer (which already has a HDD with an OS), ...). The space available in MBR is too small for modern bootloaders. That's why they have to load code from a partition. This means that the bootloader is going to fail when you format the system partition. However, if you install Ubuntu again, Grub will be installed again (will boot).